# Pareto analysis in Oracle SQL without iterative procedures and hardcoding of valid values

Tags: database, plsql, oracle11g

Say, you have table T(C1, C2, C3) and there is a set of valid values for C1, V={v1,v2,v3...}. Now, without resorting to cursors - i.e., completely staying in the domain of set-based logic, you want to see what proportion of rows is of type v1, what proportion of rows is of type v2, and what proportion of rows is of type v3 and so on - without having to write a case if for each valid value. So, for each distinct valid value in C1, display in the result set the sorted frequency of type V rows and the corresponding value (ie, v1,v2,v3...). What is the query in PL/SQL?

EDIT: the count is straightforward:

```
select count(*) count, c1 from T group by c1 order by count
```

but what if you want to show the frequency proportions?

Comment: You can't put a `DISTINCT` there (and you wouldn't want to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you, it sounds like you just want

```
SELECT c1, count(*) cnt
  FROM t
 GROUP BY c1
 ORDER BY count(*) desc
```

That will return the sorted frequency of each value.  If you are looking for ratios, you can add the `RATIO_TO_REPORT` analytic function

```
SELECT c1, 
       cnt,
       ratio_to_report(cnt) over () fraction
  FROM (
    SELECT c1, count(*) cnt
      FROM t
     GROUP BY c1 )
 ORDER BY cnt desc
```

Comment: this will show the absolute frequency, but i want it relative to the count (just like the other question you answered from me today)...but there are so many valid values that i cant be bothered to write a "case if" for each value

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn - I updated my answer.  It's always helpful to post some sample data and the expected output to make things clearer.

Comment: i am in awe. i mean it's one thing to know this but also to implement so beautifully. thanks a lot